# SSL VPN - Your connection is encrypted with obsolete cryptography

Tags: ssl, vpn

I have a SSL VPN deployed using DigiCert issued certificates.
DigiCert says I have the SHA2 certificate.

But Chrome reports that the key exchange mechanism is "Your connection is encrypted with obsolete cryptography" TLS 1.0.

Does this pose a security risk? and how do I get out of this?

My options for cipher-suite are:

```
2911(config)#ip http secure-ciphersuite ?
  3des-ede-cbc-sha  Encryption type ssl_rsa_with_3des_ede_cbc_sha ciphersuite
  des-cbc-sha       Encryption type ssl_rsa_with_des_cbc_sha ciphersuite
  rc4-128-md5       Encryption type ssl_rsa_with_rc4_128_md5 ciphersuite
  rc4-128-sha       Encryption type ssl_rsa_with_rc4_128_sha ciphe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS 1.0 has some known security holes, you should be using TLS 1.1, and preferrably TLS 1.2 if you can.

Your "key exchange mechanism" refers to the protocol you are using TLS/SSL.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.0

The security concerns for TLS 1.0 is primarily referred to as Heartbleed.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed

I've provided you with some sources, so that you can educate yourself on topics.  Follow the instructions posted by CJS to help solve your specific dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Digicert is issued with SHA2, it's the problem with VPN server(router in your case).

You need to:

(1) Change your cipher-suite to 3DES or higher.

(2) Regenerate rsa keys using "crypto key generate ec "

(3) Regenerate CSR with new trustpoint with the rsa key created in previous step

(4) Submit CSR to CA and get new ones

(5) Load the new certificates